# Eclipse + PyDev: how to import Django project (error with relative path to manage.py)

Tags: django, eclipse-plugin, pydev

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) + PyDev plugin.
Virtualenv
```

My project is called "superlists". I cloned it from github and imported into Eclipse, then performed "Set as Django" and tried to follow PyDev faq about Django project configuration (http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIimportexistingprojects%2FsourcesforaDjangoprojectintoPyDev%3F)

The project has  ordinary directory structure.

```
superlists
    superlists
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    manage.py
```

I have gone to Window/Preferences/PyDev/Interpreters/Python Interpreter,
selected String Substitution Variables and set:

```
DJANGO_MANAGE_LOCATION manage.py
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE superlists.settings.py
```

Could you help me understand why I get this message:

> /home/michael/venv/gmv_venv/bin/python: can't open file
>   '/home/michael/workspace/superlists/src/my_project/manage.py': [Errno
>   2] No such file or directory

I mean why it looks for manage.py in src/my_project/manage.py? And how to cope with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I should have made a right click on the project and select PyDev - Pythonpath and set variables there.